# django-rest-social-auth login with give me error 400 bad request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, django-socialauth, django-rest-auth

guys im working on django-rest-social-auth that is here in github 
https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth
and trying to add google login to my django rest framwork app
first i get `code` from this url

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id={{CLIENT_ID}}&redirect_uri={{REDIRECT_URL}}&scope=email
```

then
i send  needed parameter like `clientId`,`redirect_uri`,`provider` and `code` to

```
http://localhost:8000/api/login/social/jwt/google/
```

with postman and browser form but :

i get `HTTP 400 Bad Request` error also i see this in my server console :

```
    raise AuthForbidden(args[0])
social_core.exceptions.AuthForbidden: Your credentials aren't allowed
```

this is the data that i post :

```
  {   
    "clientId": "61235520-pn78ds5sds5d21d21jmn1e9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "provider": "google-oauth2",
    "code": "4%2Fto7CCGznNFgE-rsssPlEQzV3lY9yjUWW_85YmPWF4OU"
  }
```

why ???

Comment: Do you have the `auth_allowed` pipeline enabled? If that's the case, what are your `WHITELIST` settings?